# Socket bind failed errno = 99

Tags: linux, sockets, errno

I'm trying to bind the server socket so I can receive and listen for incoming messages from other clients. But I can't bind, it returns an error - Socket bind failed: 99. I read up what does it mean and it says that errno 99 indicates that the socket does not exist? Any ideas? Thanks

```
  UDP_socketID = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
  if (UDP_socketID < 0)
  {
    printf("Socket creation failed! Error = %d\n\n", errno);
    exit(0);
  }

  //specify server address, port and IP
  bzero((char *)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
  serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  serverAddr.sin_port = htons(SERV_PORT);
  check = inet_aton(SERVER_IP, &serverAddr.sin_addr);
  if (check == 0)
printf("IP conversion error!\n\n");

  start = bind(UDP_socketID, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
  if (start < 0) {
    printf("Socket bind failed = %d\n", errno);
    exit(0);
}
  else
    printf("Socket bind successful!\n");
```

Answer (score 11):

99 is EADDRNOTAVAIL. Which means (from man bind(2)):

> A nonexistent interface was requested or the requested address was not
>   local.

Maybe the `SERVER_IP` is not IP of your host.

Comment: Use `perror` or `strerror(errno)` to get a human message associated to `errno`

Comment: Oh no! It returned: "Cannot assign requested address." The server IP is on another host, not me. How can I fix this?

Comment: @Broccoli : Assuming that this is server side code. If you don't care which interface your server listens, then you can remove SERVER_IP  stuff and simply bind the server socket with INADDR_ANY.

Comment: @Broccoli : And give destination host IP to sendto() function.