# Socket bind returns error 99

Tags: linux, sockets, udp

When I am accessing more that 1 service from the server side, bind returns '*error 99 (invalid address)*'.

However it works normally when I access only 1 service at a time. Why is this happening ?

**This is how I access the IP address**

`serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = if_addr(TcpIp_Config[handleId].StaticIpAddr)`

**Place where the error occurs**

```
if(0 > bind(UDP_socketID, (struct sockaddr *) serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr))
{
    perror(bind());
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Socket bind failed errno = 99](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16784530/socket-bind-failed-errno-99)

Answer (score 0):

Please check!

```
if(0 > bind(UDP_socketID, (struct sockaddr *) serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr))
```

& is missing:

```
if(0 > bind(UDP_socketID, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr))
```

Comment: I missed it over here. Its present it acctual code. However it did not help..!